# Converting a timestamp to PHP date format for a field in a node template

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, theming, datetime

I have an imagefield, 'event_image' and printing all possible variables for the field tells me I have timestamp as a possible variable of the image to render. I use:

```
print '<pre>';
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
print '</pre>

// renders:
["timestamp"]=>
string(10) "1348629688"
```

... in `node--mycustom.tpl.php` to get the variables.

Now I can render the timestamp as such:

```
<?php print $node->field_event_image['und'][0]['timestamp'] ?>
```

... and it prints a UNIX formatted timestamp as:

```
1348629688
```

I'd like to convert this to a PHP date format. So I am guessing I would need to convert the UNIX timestamp somehow using the PHP `gmdate` function. Typically I would use something like this for raw php:

```
  $mytimestamp=1348629688;
  print gmdate("m-d-Y", $mytimestamp);
```

Which would take my timestamp and output:

```
09-26-2012
```

... but I just don't know how to do within the context of my drupal 7 field and the node template.

**UPDATE:**

Base on clive's comment below, it turns out a preprocess function is the way to go:
So in my theme's template.php file I now have:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {

$node = $vars['node'];
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_event_image');
$vars['upload_date'] = format_date($field_items[0]['timestamp'], 'mdy');

}
```

... and then in my custom node template, I have:

```
<?php print $upload_date; ?>
```

Note, `'mdy'` is a custom format I set in the Drupal UI. That's better than using `gmdate` I suppose.

Comment: drupal is in php so all functions in php is valid here too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out by  Mohammed Shameem:

```
<?php print gmdate("m-d-Y", $node->field_event_image['und'][0]['timestamp']) ?>
```

However, the Drupal way would be:

```
<?php print format_date($node->field_event_image['und'][0]['timestamp'], 'short'); ?>
```

The latter construct will render the date in the standard short date format set up for the site.  The former will use the format *you* pick.  The Drupal way ensures that the date format is standardized throughout the site.

Comment: Actually the Drupal way would be `$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_event_image'); $vars['event_date'] = format_date($field_items[0]['value'], 'short');`, run in a preprocess function ;)

Comment: These are both nice, thanks! @Clive Why would you favor running this in a preprocess function?  Is it a security risk or some other issue with doing this in a node?

Comment: It's just good practice to separate logic from display...templates should only really be used to print variables, preprocess functions should be used to prepare them. Also your code becomes more reusable, as other modules/themes in the system will have a chance to override those variable if/when necessary

Comment: Also, using `format_date()` parts of the date are translated in the language set for the content; for example, _Jan_ would become _Gen_ when Italian is set as language, and _Monday_ would become _Giovedì_.

Comment: See my "update" in the original question above for the full code for a preprocess function based on Clive's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another example based on field in user object:

```
  global $user; 
  $curr_user = user_load($user->uid);
  $field_items = field_get_items('user', $curr_user, 'field_some_date_end');

  $datetime = $field_items[0]['value']; // Unix time
  $formatted = format_date($datetime, 'short'); // Date in short format
```